# How to properly test a local DNS server locally?

Tags: networking, dns, ip, nslookup

#### Context

I intended to set up a local DNS server with Technitium and would like to verify the local DNS server returns the correct response when it is being queried for a domain. It does not work while  using `nslookup mydomain.com`. I expect that to be because the local dns server is not reached from a public/internet place.

To exclude that this is caused by my local DNS server not working correctly (locally), I would like to verify that at least the local DNS server returns the correct IP address if it is queried for my domain.

#### Attempts

The local DNS server runs on local IP address `127.0.0.1` at port `5379` hence I tried the following commands followed by their respective outputs:

```
nslookup 127.0.0.1 somedomain.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

nslookup 127.0.0.1:5379 somedomain.com
nslookup: couldn't get address for 'somedomain.com': failure

nslookup http://127.0.0.1:5379 somedomain.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached

nslookup https://127.0.0.1:5379 somedomain.com
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

So either the testing command `nslookup 127.0.0.1:5379 somedomain.com` is a possible way to test whether the local DNS server returns the correct IP address when it is queried some domain, and I have not set up the local DNS server correctly, or I am using an incorrect testing command.

#### Question

How can one test the whether the response of a local DNS server returns the correct IP address when it is queried for a domain (from the device that hosts the DNS server)?

Comment: I suggest using `dig` instead, it should offer more verbose output. // DNS is not HTTP so throwing URLs at `nslookup` isn’t going to work.

Comment: [nslookup is a badly flawed tool](https://jdebp.uk/FGA/nslookup-flaws.html).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your nslookup syntax is backwards: the server goes *after* the domain name.

```
nslookup example.com 127.0.0.1
```

You cannot specify a custom port with Windows' nslookup. (Although it has a hidden `-port=` option, but unfortunately it is ignored.)

URLs will not work here: DNS is not HTTP-based. *(There is a specification for carrying DNS messages inside HTTP, but it requires special clients and servers.)*

If you have Linux or some BSD available (Windows Subsystem for Linux will work too), there's a wider variety of tools such as `dig`, `drill`, or `delv`. For example:

```
host -p 5379 example.com 127.0.0.1

dig @127.0.0.1 -p 5379 example.com
```

Answer (score 2):

As several people have noted, the weakness with [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1647415/1249358) is that a ping resolving doesn't prove that your DNS server answered.  It just proves that some DNS server did.  Assuming you can't switch from nslookup to a different command that supports specifying the port (as suggested in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/1647421/1249358)), then I see two options that might help you:

1. Turn off your DNS server so that it definitely is not answering.  Attempt the ping, if it returns nothing then but does provide results when you turn the server on, then it's working.  Weakness:  it won't work if the internet can resolve the address.
2. Unplug the network cable.  Verify that you can't reach anything (so you know that you don't have a WiFi connection or anything like that).  Attempt the ping with the server off (to make sure it isn't cached).  Then turn the DNS server on and try the ping again.

Note that in either case, everything has to be configured correctly.  So your computer needs to be configured to use your local DNS server and the local DNS server has to be configured to answer the request.  If it doesn't work, either of those things might be broken.  That's why switching to a different DNS client that supports port selection might be better.  Then you could test the client against known good servers and the now verified client against your server.

Another option would be port forwarding.  The nslookup command will use port 53.  If you configure things so that requests to 53 get forwarded to the correct port, that would also allow a request to go through.  Again though, it adds additional things that can be not working.  Is the DNS server broken?  Or is port forwarding misconfigured?  Either could give the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I will try to put here a complete example, including exposing a zone from a local dns server.

We will use bind9 as name server on a Ubuntu 21 machine.

First of all define your zones in a file, I used etc/bind/example.com.zone, modifying [this example](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/13/html/Deployment_Guide/s2-bind-zone-examples.html)
Docs: https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference.html#zone-file

```
$ORIGIN example.com.
$TTL 30
@       SOA     localhost. admin.example.com.   (
                2001062501 ; serial
                21600      ; refresh after 6 hours
                3600       ; retry after 1 hour
                604800     ; expire after 1 week
                86400 )    ; minimum TTL of 1 day
;
;
        NS      localhost. ;
        NS      dns1.example.com.
        NS      dns2.example.com.
dns1    A       10.0.1.1
        AAAA    aaaa:bbbb::1
dns2    A       10.0.1.2
        AAAA    aaaa:bbbb::2
bar     CNAME   www.example.com
```

Now you should load this zone from the bind conf file /etc/bind/named.conf, like this

```
zone "example.com." IN {
  type master;
  file "/etc/bind/example.com.zone";
  allow-update {none; };
};
```

I have also added some extra option to the named service /etc/bind/named.conf.options

```
options {
  ;---OTHER STUFF
  listen-on port 53 { any; };
  allow-query       { any; };
  recursion       yes;
};
```

Then you can restart the services
`sudo systemctl restart named bind9`

Finally test your zones, you can use what you prefer between dig, host, resolvectl or nslookup.

`$ host -t A dns1.example.com localhost`

```
Using domain server:
Name: localhost
Address: 127.0.0.1#53
Aliases: 

dns1.example.com has address 10.0.1.1
```

`$ host -t AAAA dns1.example.com localhost`

```
Using domain server:
Name: localhost
Address: 127.0.0.1#53
Aliases: 

dns1.example.com has IPv6 address aaaa:bbbb::1
```

`$ host -t CNAME bar.example.com localhost`

```
Using domain server:
Name: localhost
Address: 127.0.0.1#53
Aliases: 

bar.example.com is an alias for www.example.com.example.com.
```

[image: bind9 test from host to guest virtual machine]

Answer (score -1):

### Windows

You can use nslookup, as Grawity mentioned your syntax was wrong.

[image]

You can also use the tools from [Bind9](https://www.isc.org/download/) on windows, you do not need the Windows Subsystem for Linux to use them anymore. it doesn't need to be installed. Just unzip it somewhere convenient for command line usage. (comes with dig, delv, host, nslookup, etc) The bind9-nslookup seems to be able to use the hidden port argument that Grawity mentioned in his answer.
[image: nslookup-w-port]

---

### dig

Debian and Ubuntu install:

```
sudo apt-get install dnsutils
```

CentOS 7 install:

```
yum install bind-utils
```

---

A typical use of dig looks like this:

```
dig @server name type
```

[image: dig]

**where:**

**server**

```
is the name or IP address of the name server to query. This can be an IPv4 address in dotted-decimal notation or an IPv6 address in colon-delimited notation. When the supplied server argument is a hostname, dig resolves that name before querying that name server.

If no server argument is provided, dig consults /etc/resolv.conf; if an address is found there, it queries the name server at that address. If either of the -4 or -6 options are in use, then only addresses for the corresponding transport will be tried. If no usable addresses are found, dig will send the query to the local host. The reply from the name server that responds is displayed.
```

**name**

```
is the name of the resource record that is to be looked up.
```

**type**

```
indicates what type of query is required — ANY, A, MX, SIG, etc. type can be any valid query type. If no type argument is supplied, dig will perform a lookup for an A record.
```

---

### delv

A typical use of delv looks like:

```
        delv @server name type
```

[image: delv]

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man1/delv.1.html

---

or you can just use the quick and dirty ping for this.

Full disclosure:
If you need to know whether or not your local LAN private server is responding using this method, you need to only have 127.0.0.1 as the first and only DNS server in the network adapters configuration, on the computer running the server app.

**Ping mydomain.com** and check if it displays the right IP number.

127.0.0.1 is the computers loop-back address, only your local OS can communicate with this IP number.

Make sure the service is attached to a local IP address if you want other computers on the LAN to be able to use the local DNS service.

Don't forget to add the local IP of the DNS service to the adapter settings of other computers on the LAN.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that your answer implies that `ping mydomain.com` will always check the local IP addresses that are available for a DNS server that happens to have an IP address entry for `mydomain.com` before they go out on the internet to look at some default DNS server?

Comment: I’m confused. How would you use `ping` to check whether a DNS server is working? Especially a DNS server that is, from what I understand, not set up in `resolv.conf`.

Comment: This will test that *a* server is capable of resolving the address, but not that a *specific* server is resolving it.